# Node.js and Sphinx concurrent connection issue on Server

Tags: node.js, sphinx, npm

I have been using Sphinx Technology for site and implemented in php and Node.js. Using php and Sphinx, so far i didn't get any issues. But with Node.js and Sphinx, i got the following issues rapidly,

```
1. Error: Error: Connection is opening in OnConnect
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/limestone/limestone.js:217:26)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:64:17)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:614:10)

2. node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
    Error: write EPIPE
        at errnoException (net.js:640:11)
        at Object.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:478:18)
```

I have been using limestone node.js module as middleware between Node.js and Sphinx server. My assumption is that above error is occured due to the concurrent connection request to Sphinx. If so, then how to avoid the concurrent sphinx request.

Please suggest on the same.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using sphinxql via one of mysql libraries available for sphinx.